# Can I disable the message line when launching ``screen -RR``

Tags: gnu-screen

`screen -RR` is great. It does one of the two thing automatically:

- If there is any detached screen session, it picks up one can attach to it.
- If there is no detached screen session(no session yet, or all have been attach to other terminal), it creates a new screen session automatically.

I use Windows server Remote Desktop a lot, `screen -RR` behaves almost the same when a client connects to a remote desktop server. It is natural and I like it.

However, when `screen -RR` determines it should create a new session, it displays a message line at terminal bottom for 5 second. I'd like to suppress this message line because it brings us little benefit. In my opinion, a remote user can always easily distinguish whether he is connected to a resumed session(a piled-up display) or a newly created session(a clean display) from what he sees in the terminal window.

[image]

So, is there a way to suppress the nag "New screen..." ? Just suppress that very one, not suppress message line globally.

My env: opensuse 11.3, GNU screen 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Comment: "a remote user can always easily distinguish" -- no he can't.

Comment: No problem. In case he can't, he just settles with it and type his linux command to do his job. If he can't, I'm afraid he as well does not know what "New screen..." mean. In my idea ``screen -RR'' is set up by the sys admin(e.g., from the login script) and used by normal users silently.

Answer (score 8):

use the option

```
msgwait 0
```

in your .screenrc

Also, you may want to turn off the startup message as well

```
startup_message off
```

Answer (score 2):

It's open source, so I doubt these futures can be disabled with a single command argument. My answer would be:

Have a look at the source code, comment  out the lines you don't need and compile screen for your machines.

Comment: I would rather refrain from doing that until there is a way to do it using "standard" screen. I'm not powerful enough to make that customization.

Comment: You could at least look at the source to see if there *is* any way to do it.